# Como ordenar array de objetos por números o letras

Tags: javascript, array, ordenamiento

Tengo un array array que ordeno con la funcion sort() y comparo pero no me los ordena asi: 1 2 , 111, 86, los ordeno por la propiedad nombre de mi arreglo que siempre es un string y algunas veces trae numero al inicio o otras no.

```
const data = [
               {
                  "nombre":"1 AG des",
                
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"18 RT des",
               
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"19 AG Inven",
              
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"21 SH Inven",
               
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"124 AG House",
             
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"160 XR ",
                 
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"170 AG ",
                
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"50 RETY",
                
               },
               {
                  "nombre":"JITE",
               
               }]
```

la funcion que utilizo para ordenar

```
data.sort((valorA: any, valorB: any) => {

                const nombreA = valorA.nombre.toUpperCase();
                const nombreB = valorB.nombre.toUpperCase();

                if (nombreA < nombreB) {
                    return -1;
                }

                if (nombreA > nombreB) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return 0;
```

esta funcion lo ordena pero solo toma en cuenta el primer caracter, tambien probe usando un substring (0,3) a los nombres sin el resultado esperado

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia es:

1. Dividir los valores por espacios, creando un arreglo
2. Analizar si el primer elemento de cada arreglo es numérico
3. Si ambos son iguales y numéricos, comparar el resto de la cadena
4. De lo contrario, realizar la comparación normal de `sort`, agregando la condición si uno es numérico y el otro no

```js
const data = [
    {"nombre":"1 AG des",},
    {"nombre":"18 RT des",},
    {"nombre":"19 AG Inven",},
    {"nombre":"21 SH Inven",},
    {"nombre":"124 AG House",},
    {"nombre":"160 XR ",},
    {"nombre":"170 AG ",},
    {"nombre":"50 RETY",},
    {"nombre":"JITE",},
    {"nombre":"1 AG abc",},             // Insertado para probar
    {"nombre":"1 AB debe ir primero",}  // Insertado para probar
];

data.sort((valorA, valorB) => {
    // Evitar procesar si ambos valores son iguales
    if(valorA.nombre.toUpperCase() == valorB.nombre.toUpperCase()) {
        return 0;
    }
    // Crear arreglo de "palabras", separando por espacios
    const arrA = valorA.nombre.split(' ');
    const arrB = valorB.nombre.split(' ');
    // El nombre como número o nombre completo en mayúsculas
    const nombreA = parseInt(arrA[0]) || valorA.nombre.toUpperCase();
    const nombreB = parseInt(arrB[0]) || valorB.nombre.toUpperCase();
    // Si ambos son iguales y numéricos
    if(nombreA == nombreB && Number.isInteger(nombreA) && Number.isInteger(nombreB)) {
        // Eliminar primer elemento de los dos arreglos
        arrA.shift();
        arrB.shift();
        // Unir resto de elementos y convertir en mayúsculas
        const strA = arrA.join(' ').toUpperCase();
        const strB = arrB.join(' ').toUpperCase();
        if(strA < strB) {
            return -1;
        }
        // Se puede omitir esta comparación, no hay otra posibilidad
        // if(strA > strB) {
            return 1;
        // }
    }
    // Si nombreA es menor que nombreB o nombreA es numérico y nombreB alfanumérico
    if (nombreA < nombreB || (Number.isInteger(nombreA) && !Number.isInteger(nombreB))) {
        return -1;
    }
    // Si nombreA es mayor que nombreB o nombreA es alfanumérico y nombreB numérico
    // Se puede omitir la comparación, este es el último caso posible
    // if (nombreA > nombreB || (!Number.isInteger(nombreA) && Number.isInteger(nombreB))) {
        return 1;
    // }
});

console.log(data);
```

**Nota 1:** Agregué algunos elementos para ver qué pasa cuando hay números repetidos.

**Nota 2:** Edité la respuesta para evitar operaciones y comparaciones que no son necesarias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede cuando ordenas por texto, este funciona de diferente manera aunque tenga solo numeros dentros, es por esto que debes detectar y parsear los numeros que estan dentro del string para hacer un orden correcto.

```
data.sort((a,b) => {
    if(!isNaN(a.nombre.split(' ')[0]) && !isNaN(b.nombre.split(' ')[0])) {
        return parseInt(a.nombre.split(' ')[0]) - parseInt(b.nombre.split(' ')[0])
    }
    return a.nombre - b.nombre
})
```

Basándome en el array que estregaste, tomo la primera "palabra" que en este caso son números, pregunto si son números y si lo son, los parseo y luego ordeno. Si no son numeros los ordeno como lo haria normalmente con palabras